# Query condition missed key schema element

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I have

I have a dynamodb table with partition key as id, and also i have GSI as transaction_id
I want to create new GSI for created_at field to make new query with between operator.
while building queries should i add this between operator as `expression.KeyConditionBuilder` or
`expression.ConditionBuilder` thank you for your answers
this is my implementation for db client:

```
    var keyCondBuilder expression.KeyConditionBuilder
    keyCondition.ForEach(func(key string, value db.ConditionValue) {
        if value.Operation == db.ConditionOperationEqual {
            if keyCondBuilder.IsSet() {
                keyCondBuilder = keyCondBuilder.And(expression.Key(key).Equal(expression.Value(value.Value)))
            } else {
                keyCondBuilder = expression.Key(key).Equal(expression.Value(value.Value))
            }
        } else if value.Operation == db.ConditionOperationBetween {
            if len(value.BetweenValues) != 2 {
                errors.New("between operation requires two values")
            }
            if keyCondBuilder.IsSet() {
                keyCondBuilder = keyCondBuilder.And(expression.Key(key).Between(expression.Value(value.BetweenValues[0]), expression.Value(value.BetweenValues[1])))
            } else {
                keyCondBuilder = expression.Key(key).Between(expression.Value(value.BetweenValues[0]), expression.Value(value.BetweenValues[1]))
            }
        }
    })

    builder := expression.NewBuilder().WithKeyCondition(keyCondBuilder)

    var filterCondBuilder expression.ConditionBuilder
    if filterCondition != nil {
        filterCondition.ForEach(func(key string, value db.ConditionValue) {
            if value.Operation == db.ConditionOperationEqual {
                if filterCondBuilder.IsSet() {
                    filterCondBuilder = filterCondBuilder.And(expression.Name(key).Equal(expression.Value(value.Value)))
                } else {
                    filterCondBuilder = expression.Name(key).Equal(expression.Value(value.Value))
                }
            } else if value.Operation == db.ConditionOperationBetween {
                if len(value.BetweenValues) != 2 {
                    errors.New("for BETWEEN operation, exactly two values are required")
                }
                if filterCondBuilder.IsSet() {
                    filterCondBuilder = filterCondBuilder.And(expression.Name(key).Between(expression.Value(value.BetweenValues[0]), expression.Value(value.BetweenValues[1])))
                } else {
                    filterCondBuilder = expression.Name(key).Between(expression.Value(value.BetweenValues[0]), expression.Value(value.BetweenValues[1]))
                }
            }
        })
        builder = builder.WithFilter(filterCondBuilder)
    }

    expr, err := builder.Build()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("got error when building expression: %v", err)
    }

    params := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        FilterExpression:          expr.Filter(),
        ProjectionExpression:      expr.Projection(),
        KeyConditionExpression:    expr.KeyCondition(),
        TableName:                 dbClient.TableName(),
        IndexName:                 indexName,
        ConsistentRead:            consistentRead,
    }

    result, err := dbClient.svc.Query(ctx, params)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("got error calling Query: %s", err)
    }
```